# why my app can’t use FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions class

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I tried to make an object from FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions class but my app doesn’t import it
[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgacN.png) . And this is my dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.1'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:17.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [the Cloud Landmarks API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/recognize-landmarks#configure-the-landmark-detector) so you will need the Cloud Options class

```
FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions options =
    new FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.LATEST_MODEL)
            .setMaxResults(15)
            .build();
```

The Cloud based APIs work differently to on-device ones, so the options will be slightly different.